# Is there a programming language you can not create CLI application?

Tags: command-line-interface

I received requirement to find a programming language which fulfills requirement of being CLI interactive and now I am scratching my head thinking if there is a language which does not fulfills mentioned requirement.

Comment: Visual FoxPro and Visual Basic immediately come to mind, both strongly based on GUI but with console development left behind.

Comment: To be clear, that's legacy VB. VB.Net.support CLI.

Comment: @Mike67 Indeed I was talking about the real VB, not anything .NET.